# How to prevent WiFi monitor mode reset after reboot?

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan

I have successfully set my WiFi adapter to monitor mode using these three commands:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down
sudo iw wlan0 set monitor control
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

But it seems to be reset back into "non-monitor" (managed?) mode after a reboot. How can I prevent this from happening?

This is my `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:
            addresses:
            - 10.0.0.10/24
            gateway4: 10.0.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - [[REMOVED]
        [[REMOVED]]:
            match:
                macaddress: [[REMOVED]]
            set-name: wlan0
    version: 2
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Ubuntu, 20.10 .